# Button not displaying switch from viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiwebview, sqlite, uibutton

I'm getting touch coordinates from UIWebView and store to database. Later i'm getting these values from database and if those values matches i create one button on that coordinates. I used tag for create number of buttons, but while come back from UIWebView and go to UIWebView the last coordinate button only displays all other buttons are not showing. Why?

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {



                xff=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);

                yff=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);

                art_Id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);

                NSLog(@"xff is %f",xff);

                NSLog(@"yff is %f",yff);

                //  NSLog(@"zc is %@",zc);

                NSLog(@"art_Id is %ld",(long)art_Id);


                    if(xff && yff && art_Id){

        NSLog(@"error");

        btnArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"xff is %f",xff);
        NSLog(@"yff is %f",yff);
        NSLog(@"art_idd is %ld",(long)art_Id);

        button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button1 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(click1:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button1 setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button1.frame = CGRectMake(xff, yff, 30.0, 20.0);


        button1.tag = gTag;
        gTag++;

        [wbCont.scrollView  addSubview:button1];



    }




            }
        }
    }
```

I used same code for viewDidLoad;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {



                xff=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);

                yff=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);

                art_Id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);

                NSLog(@"xff is %f",xff);

                NSLog(@"yff is %f",yff);

                //  NSLog(@"zc is %@",zc);

                NSLog(@"art_Id is %ld",(long)art_Id);



    if(xff && yff && art_Id){

        NSLog(@"error");


        NSLog(@"xff is %f",xff);
        NSLog(@"yff is %f",yff);
        NSLog(@"art_idd is %ld",(long)art_Id);

        button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button1 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(click1:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button1 setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button1.frame = CGRectMake(xff, yff, 30.0, 20.0);


        button1.tag = gTag;
        gTag++;

        [wbCont.scrollView  addSubview:button1];

        }




            }
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: I don't see a loop anywhere. You're initializing btnArray but you never use it.

Comment: Sorry i didn't use btnArray. It no need.

Comment: xff & yff is the coordinates. Is i need to use xff & yff inside for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what is your first part of code in the post is for.

Anyways, from your viewDidLoad code, I'm assuming that you will get set of coordinates(x,y) for multiple buttons and you want to create buttons in that position.

In your code, you are not creating buttons in any loop, which means you are creating only one button. My understanding is that, in your while loop, you are taking the x and y coordinates only, you need to create button also inside this loop.

Just try adding this code inside your `while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)` loop

```
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button1 addTarget:self
               action:@selector(click1:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button1 setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(xff, yff, 30.0, 20.0);
button1.tag = gTag;
gTag++;

[wbCont.scrollView  addSubview:button1];
```

Comment: When i use indise while loop, later i can't delete the button. If i delete it delete the all buttons.

Comment: Post your delete code also..